# Display Different Image On Load/Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow, jquery-events

I'm currently using Jquery Cycle plugin for my project and the slideshow is running smoothly. However, I want my slide to display or start with a different image on every page refresh. I'm not sure how to add a function/script to achieve that or if it's possible. I'm  new to JQuery so any help would greatly be appreciated!

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
         fx: 'fade',
         speed: 2500,
         timeout: 7000,
         prev: '#prev',
         next: '#next',
    });
});
```

---

My HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
    <img src="images/img_slide-1.jpg" />
    <img src="images/img_slide-2.jpg" />
    <img src="images/img_slide-3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the startingslide option

```
startingSlide: 0,     // zero-based index of the first slide to be displayed
```

To pick a random slide you need to get a random index like this

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.slideshow img').length);
```

Then, when you initiliaze the cycle, use the `rand` variable as the startingslide.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.slideshow img').length);
  $('.slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 2500,
    timeout: 7000,
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next',
    startingSlide: rand
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't "startingSlide: 0," make the slideshow always start with the 1st image on the list?

Comment: Yes but you need to change the 0. I've updated my code to pick a random one.

Comment: PS: never leave a trailing comma ',' at the end of objects. Internet Explorer will throw an error.

Comment: @ComputerArts Oh really? Wow, you learn something new every day!

Comment: Yep! Comes in handy to know... instead of wasting time and cursing IE's developers! =)

Comment: FWIW, I know the error occurs in IE7 and IE8 (if my memory is still good) not sure about IE9.

Comment: @ComputerArts I used your code just the way it is and it doesn't seem to work. Are there parameters I need to modify first?

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled startingSlide. Slide should have a capital S

Comment: OMG it's working! That's so cool. I'm actually checking the docs too and I didn't even take note of the upper hand letter, my bad.

Comment: @ComputerArts I just found another problem with my slides. It continuously slides which is ok but I want it to temporarily stop or maybe pause sliding whenever I hover the current image. I found this "pauseOnPagerHover:" but I guess I can't use that since I don't have a pager.

Comment: @Shanlais In the documentatin (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html), you have the option "pause" set it to "1" and it will enable the pause on hover like it explicitly says here: pause: 0,     // true to enable "pause on hover" ... so by changing the 0 to 1, it will pause it.

Comment: I've been checking that documentation and has tried inserting pause: 0 but the slideshow still continues. So I misinterpret the comment. assigning 1 does the work. :D

Comment: @ComputerArts Using the current code, it generates a random image to show every refresh. Is there a way to randomly select just the odd number(1st, 3rd, 5th image)? or maybe tell the slide that on every refresh show image 1, on next refresh, show image 2, on next, show image 5 and so on..

Comment: Yes you can. Here's an example I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/DyehM/. As for the refresh part, you could do it but would need to use cookies or a session variable but that's a whole different question!

Answer (score 1):

Doing some quick research on this plugin (I have never used it before), it looks like there is a random option that you can specify as true. Take a look in the docs: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html (just ctrl-f for "random").

If you were looking from just a random first picture, then sequential slides after (as stated in the comments), just use startingSlide: SLIDE_NUMBER_HERE, and it should work, based on minimal research on the docs.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but it looks like Random initial picture, but keep them sequential cycle

Comment: Ahh, if thats the case, then you should use startingSlide

Comment: Currently, the slideshow always starts with my first image and followed by the others sequentially. That's actually correct, I want it that way. What I want to add though is that on Refresh it should start with another image and would still go to the next image after that.

Comment: @Shanlais another image as another random image? If so then use `Math.floor(Math.random() * LENGTH_OF_SLIDESHOW)` to generate a random integer, and put that as the startingSlide option.

Comment: I tried to use Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) on the variable I declared and called that variable as the startingslide but every refresh still displays the first image on the list. Maybe I'm doing something incorrect. :(

Comment: yep just as it is <img src=""> should I put a class on each of them?

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console (if you are using anything other than IE) and is it returning an error somewhere?